# Spring: Bean init method is not called and its properties does not take values

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I have two similar beans. They are set to be called in a `ScheduledTimerTask`.

But one is working fine, the other is not! Here are these two configurations:

```
<!--  Clear Orders By Sessions -->
<bean id="clearExpiredSessionOrdersTask" class="com.datx.timers.ClearExpiredSessionOrdersTask" autowire="byName">
    <property name="period" value="00:02:10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clearExpiredSessionOrdersTaskInvoker"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="clearExpiredSessionOrdersTask" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="doTask" />
</bean>

<bean id="clearExpiredSessionOrdersTaskTimer" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="clearExpiredSessionOrdersTaskInvoker" />
    <property name="delay" value="1000" /><!-- In miliseconds -->
    <property name="period" value="130000" /><!-- In miliseconds -->
</bean>
<!--  Clear Orders By Sessions -->
```

This is the one which is working. My class is `com.datx.timers.ClearExpiredSessionOrdersTask` in the first line.

The other bean is set like this:

```
<!-- DocumentScheduleTask -->

<bean id="documentSchaduleTask" class="com.datx.timers.DocumentSchaduleTask" autowire="byName" init-method="init">
     <property name="period" value="00:02:10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="documentSchaduleTaskInvoker"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref ="documentSchaduleTask" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="doTask" />
</bean>

<bean id="documentSchaduleTaskTimer" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="documentSchaduleTaskInvoker" />
    <property name="delay" value="1000" /><!-- In miliseconds -->
    <property name="period" value="130000" /><!-- In miliseconds -->
</bean>


<!-- DocumentScheduleTask -->
```

Do you see the similarities? Again the first line is my class.

An this is my `DocumentScheduleTask` class:

```
public class DocumentSchaduleTask{
    private String period;
    public init(){
       System.out.println("Test");
    }
    public void doTask(){
        //This method is called at a specific time
    }

    public void setPeriod(String period){
        this.period = period;
    }
    public String getPeriod(){
        return this.period;
    }
}
```

The rest of these configurations are the same. But in the second one the `period` property does no take value. And its `init` method is not called. What are these implying?

Why would have caused this? Where should I look for? Do you see any differences at all?

Comment: What's the code of your DocumentSchaduleTask class?

Comment: I updated my answer and put the `DocumentScheduleTask` class.

Answer (score 0):

My one concern about this difference is `init` method in the second configuration. AFAIK `init` called after properties set to bean, so maybe it is possible that code in your `init` method clear that value. Please, add sources of your init method for DocumentSchaduleTask.

And, maybe, your typo Sch **a** duler causes some problems as you autowire by name.